# Swift 3 Draggable UIButton

Tags: swift, button, uigesturerecognizer, pan

Apologies as I'm still learning the basics of Swift.

I'm trying to move a button when I drag it which sounds simple.  I can't figure out how to pass along the sender information to the drag function so I can associate it with the button that is being dragged.

I create multiple one word buttons which are only text and attach a pan gesture recognizer to each of them:

```
let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panButton(_:)))
let word = UIButton(type: .system)
word.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
```

I've created this function to trigger when the button is moved:

```
func panButton(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    if sender.state == .began {
        //wordButtonCenter = button.center // store old button center
    } else if sender.state == .ended || sender.state == .failed || sender.state == .cancelled {
        //button.center = wordButtonCenter // restore button center
    } else {
        let location = sender.location(in: view) // get pan location
        //button.center = location // set button to where finger is
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'panButton'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @benjamin points out in Swift 3 you needs to be a selector. I've updated my code to the following in order to extract the button tag:

```
let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.panGestureHandler(panGesture:)))
    panGesture.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1
    let word = UIButton(type: .system)
```

With the following selector:

```
@objc func panGestureHandler(panGesture recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let buttonTag = (recognizer.view?.tag)!
    if let button = view.viewWithTag(buttonTag) as? UIButton {

        if recognizer.state == .began {
            wordButtonCenter = button.center // store old button center
        } else if recognizer.state == .ended || recognizer.state == .failed || recognizer.state == .cancelled {
            button.center = wordButtonCenter // restore button center
        } else {
            let location = recognizer.location(in: view) // get pan location
            button.center = location // set button to where finger is
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, your action needs to be a selector in Swift 3. So that would look something like this:

```
let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panButton(_:))
```

Also, you can't pass the value of a button through a selector, so you would need to change your func to be:

```
func panButton(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    ...
}
```

If you're wondering how you are supposed to find the button if you can't pass it as a parameter, then you might consider using tags.

Comment: I'm getting an error using your example using the following code:

error

    Use of unresolved identifier 'panButton'

            let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panButton(_:)))


        func panButton (sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

Comment: You shouldn't be. Your code looks right. Perhaps if you edit your post with the updated code I can take a look.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look.  I've updated the question with my current code.